Can we automatically click the SSO login option in Salesforce community
Flow

Login on an Web app(SP) via an IDP. Session is created between Wepapp and IDP on IDP.
Now, in that web app, we are opening salesforce community in a popup.
3.in Popup, Login  SSO via  button is displayed. Now after clicking on the button, salesforce community page is opening. Same IDP is used for webpage and salesforce Community.
4.We are closing Popup automatically and reloading the parent webpage.

Requirement is -
Can we somehow bypass the Login sso button in community login page.
Or
Can we automatically click on the login sso button via script or something.
So that user can avoid clicking and automatically redirected back to parent webapp. Is there any api call needed between salesforce and IDP
Thank you in advance.
